# jQuery select href values in nested divds

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, href, attr

Although I found several answers to select a href attribute neither of them is working for me. Maybe someone can help.

The html is as follows

```
<div class="galleryitem">
   <div class="itemlink">
      <a href="page1.html">Page</a>                 
   </div>
   <div class="itemimg">
      <a href="img/test1.png">test1.png</a>                 
   </div>
</div>

<div class="galleryitem">       
   <div class="itemlink">
    <a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>                 
   </div>
   <div class="itemimg">
      <a href="img/test2.png">test2.png</a>                 
   </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to geht all the attribute values in the hrefs and tried with

```
$('.galleryitem').each(function() {

   var link = $(this).children('itemlink a').attr('href');
   var img = $(this).children(".itemimg a").attr("href");       

   //jQuery("#somediv").append("<a href='" + link + "'><img class='cloudcarousel' src='" + img + "'/></a>");

});
```

I dont know why link and img are undefined. Even $(this).children('.itemlink a') is undefined.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: have you placed your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('.galleryitem').each(function() {
    var link = $(this).find('itemlink a').attr('href');
    var img = $(this).find(".itemimg a").attr("href"); 
    //...
})
```

Comment: You missed the class with itemlink. -1

Comment: @gibberish: not sure what you mean

Comment: @John ツ: find and children are not the same. Please take a look to the documentation of children http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 2):

you want to sure the `.find()` method instead of `.children` which only grabs the immediate descendants. (you also have a small error missing the period in `itemlink`)

```
var link = $(this).find('.itemlink a').attr('href');
var img = $(this).find(".itemimg a").attr("href");
```

should work for you, and here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hQeu3/

the reason `.children` doesn't works is that there are no immediate descendents that match this selector '.itemlink a'. jQuery grabs the divs (".itemlink"), and then tries to filter to the selector, which fails in this case. it is essentially equal to

```
$(this).children().filter('.itemlink a'); //won't work!
```

if you want to use children you could do

```
$(this).children('.itemlink').children("a").attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do as follows:

```
$('.galleryitem').each(function() {

   var link = $('.itemlink > a', this).attr('href');
   var img = $('.itemimg > a', this).attr('href');
});
```

which take into account that `.itemlink` and `.itemimg` are a direct parent of the `<a>` element.